# How to select column from 2nd level depth subquery?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have found a few answers how to select a column from subquery, but it doesn't seem to be working if there is a subquery inside subquery.

My table relationships are as follow (simplified, with example):

```
Plans
| id | role_id
| --------------
| 4  | 2

Roles
| id | name
----------------
| 2  | Operator

Assignments
| role_name | user_id
| ---------------------
| Operator  | 12
```

Table `Plans` have foreign key `role_id` to table `Roles` column `id`. And Table `Roles` have foreign key `id` to table `Assignments` column `role_name`.

I'm writing a query that would select `Plans` but instead of `role_id` I would show `user_id` from table `Assignments`.

I'm pretty close with my current work but I'm stuck at final step:

```
SELECT assigned_user, plan.id, plan.role_id
FROM `Plans` AS plan
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT roleTable.id, roleTable.name 
    FROM `Roles` AS roleTable
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT base_assign.user_id AS assigned_user, base_assign.role_name 
        FROM `Assignments` AS base_assign) AS roleAssign
    ON roleTable.name = roleAssign.role_name
) AS role 
ON (plan.assignee_role = role.id)
```

Column `assigned_user` on `SELECT` part (line 1) is not found but I tried by adding alias inside of subquery `SELECT`. How I can select `base_assign.user_id`? Note that I (most likely) cannot modify database structure as it was given like this in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating subqueries too excessively and you don't even need subqueries for this. Subqueries can be materialized by optimzer in MySQL which can cause performance issues.

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/subquery-optimization.html

Try this using simple `left join`s:

```
select a.user_id as assigned_user,
    p.id,
    p.role_id
from `Plans` p
left join `Roles` r on p.assignee_role = r.id
left join `Assignments` a on r.name = a.role_name;
```

You query wasn't working because you were not selecting the column while joining.

Your somewhat "fixed" code:

```
select assigned_user,
    plan.id,
    plan.role_id
from `Plans` as plan
left join (
    select roleAssign.assigned_user roleTable.id,
        roleTable.name
    from `Roles` as roleTable
    inner join (
        select base_assign.user_id as assigned_user,
            base_assign.role_name
        from `Assignments` as base_assign
        ) as roleAssign on roleTable.name = roleAssign.role_name
    ) as role on (plan.assignee_role = role.id)
```

Comment: That worked, indeed. Multiple joins don't work they way I thought they work... Yes, sometimes I'm using complex queries because it's like my nature: I can't find another way at that time.

Comment: @EdvinTenovimas - Happens to us all at some point of time. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need subqueries for this.  It is a little confusing what you are trying to do.  The following will return all plans, even those with no `roles` and no `assignments`:

```
SELECT b.user_id as assigned_user, p.id, p.role_id
FROM Plans p LEFT JOIN
     Roles r
     ON p.role_id = r.id LEFT JOIN
     Assignments a
     ON a.name = r.name;
```

Subqueries are bad for two reasons.  In MySQL, the are materialized.  That means extra overhead for reading and writing the tables.  Plus, you lose any indexes on them.

In your case, the subqueries just add layer upon layer of naming, and the names really do not help make your query more understandable.

Comment: I have read about subqueries and why they are not quite good but I thought it's the only way to retrieve required column. I use confusing queries because... I'm facing difficulties with finding the easiest way (my nature).